# WPF window and controls style

Tags: c#, wpf, styles

I have defined in my `WPF` application all the styles that I want to apply. The problem is that if I open an other window it doesn't have the same style of the main window because it is defined in an other project.

How can I apply the styles of the main application?

Thank you!

**EDIT**

This is a part of my App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>        
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
             <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/Styles/Themes/Dark.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/Styles/Border.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/Styles/BaseBlock.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/Styles/Buttons.xaml" />
            .....
```

What I need is to apply the styles defined in the Main Project to the ones defined in Project1 in order to have uniformity.

[image]

Comment: Are the projects in the same solution?

Comment: Yes, they are. MainProject has Project1 in its references.

Answer (score 0):

Put your styles to the ResourceDictionary of your application resources in App.xaml. So you can use your resources everywhere via {StaticResource keyOfYourStyle}. If you want, that your styles be applied to all controls of the type, then use default styles:

```
<Style TargetType="Border" BasedOn="{StaticResource keyOfYourStyle}>



 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
    <ThisResourceWillBeAccessedEveryWhere x:Key="ResName"/>
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/YourAssembley;component/Resources/ButtonStyles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Could you explain me a little more about what I should put in App.xaml? I edited my post showing the start of my App.xaml. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I already do this for all the window that I have defined in my current project. 
The problem is for the windows defined in other projects to which the main application is referenced to. They have their style which can be different from the one of the main application.

Comment: If you set explicitly the style in another windows, then this will override the default style.

Comment: Probably I didn't explain well the problem. The style of all the windows defined in my project are correctly set based on the xaml.
The problem is that I have to use some WPF windows defined in other different projects.